# Replace paticular element inside all parentheses

Tags: python, regex

All a specific letter, let's say 'A', needs to be replaced in all parentheses.

For example,

```
A. (AbbAAbb) .A. (bbAbbAbA) .A. (bbbbAbbbb)
```

I want to replace all 'A' in the parenthese with '' to end up like this:

```
A. (bbbb) .A. (bbbbb) .A. (bbbbbbbb)
```

Any possible to do this in only regular expression?

Comment: You want to remove it?

Comment: You're saying random numbers of an element in your title, but *all* of a specific element in your question.  Please post a desired output

Comment: No, not pure regex in Python `re`, but you may use `re.sub(r'\([^()]+\)', lambda x: x.group().replace('A', ''), s)` if you want to remove all `A` inside `(...)`. The same can be done with just a regex if you use PyPi regex module, [`regex.sub(r'(?<=\([^()]*)A(?=[^()]*\))', '', s)`](http://rextester.com/GBJT70933).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you should post that as an answer, you had it here first

Comment: Need a callback to do this. But, it's really the simplest thing in regexland to do. Just match `\(([^()}+)\)` . In the callback just replace the a's then return the new string with paren's around it. Btw, don't use assertions, it will slow the regex down significantly.

Comment: @user3483203 I updated the question, hope it clarify something.

Comment: Can parentheses be nested?

Comment: no nested parentheses at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a common workaround for such situations - no unbalanced / nested  parentheses (as they are) should exist. You look for `A`s that follow a closing parenthesis without matching a parenthesis:

```
A(?=[^)(]*\))
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/p1VIME/1)

Python code:

```
re.sub(r"A(?=[^)(]*\))", "", str)
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, the pure/only regex way to match all 'A's in parentheses. a little risky, thought.

Comment: @revo I'll edit my question to suit to your anwser. It's clear.

Comment: @minion If you have neither nested parenthesis nor unbalanced ones this wouldn't be risky.

Comment: @revo WiktorStribiżew shows one case that end up wrong, regex101.com/r/FH1zBY/1 . What do you think about it?

Comment: @minion Good point. I changed the logic from a negative lookahead to a positive. Enforcing a closing parenthesis to exist. Please see update.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew My intentions were clear. If I have missed something more in my answer that I should add to make OP aware of it I'd be happy to know.

Answer (score 6):

With Python `re`, it is not possible to just use a plain regex, you may use a replacement callback method inside `re.sub`.

If you want to remove all `A` inside `(...)` you may use

```
re.sub(r'\([^()]+\)', lambda x: x.group().replace('A', ''), s)
```

Here, `\([^()]+\)` matches `(`, 1+ chars other than `(` and `)`, and then a `)`, passes the match value to the lambda expression (`x`) and the match text is accessible via `m.group()` (if you define capturing groups, you may access them usign `.group(n)`). With a mere `replace('A', '')`, you achieve what you need.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/On8D7g)

The same can be done with a plain regex if you use PyPi regex module:

```
regex.sub(r'(?<=\([^()]*)A(?=[^()]*\))', '', s)
```

See [this Python demo](http://rextester.com/GBJT70933).

Here, the lookarounds are used, and this works because PyPi supports infinite-width lookbehinds.

Comment: `"a"` instead of `""`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Whatever.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll change question to "a" to ''. It's more understandable.

Comment: @minion Good, suit yourself. Note that my solutions are for cases when you really need to replace something inside parentheses. The `A(?![^()]*\()` solution will not work in all 100% cases that is why I never post that kind of work arounds if there are more precise ways.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you please explain more? Would you make an example to show revo's answer doesn't work?

Comment: @minion See http://regex101.com/r/FH1zBY/1, last `A` is removed and it is not inside parentheses. Well, there is a problem with defining a string between parentheses. Is `( ( A )` inside parentheses here? If yes, you should replace all `[^()]` with `[^)]` in my patterns. If you also decide that `A` in `(bb(d(dcv)A))` is also inside parentheses, you would need a different approach. With PyPi regex, it would be `regex.sub(r'\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\)', lambda x: x.group().replace('A', ''), s)`.