# Python: How to remove commas inside parentheses?

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, pattern-matching

I'm trying to remove commas from a string using regex, but only if the commas are inside parentheses. Haven't found a similar question answered before for Python.

Example string:
`John Doe, model (dell, 24-inch)`

Desired output:
`John Doe, model (dell 24-inch)`

Comment: The correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50994231/3832970 The accepted answer there is wrong.

Comment: this seems to work: `re.sub(", (?=[^(]*\\))"," ", str)` Any reason it would fail?

Comment: Sure, here - https://regex101.com/r/KtXk78/1. You can't use lookahead only as it does not ensure a match is **inside** parentheses.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you!

Comment: I'm trying to use this in the pandas replace function, but getting `look-behind requires fixed-width pattern` error. Any idea how to make it work in pandas?

Comment: Don't use that regex that is only supported with PyPi. Try either `pd_series.str.replace(r'\([^()]*\)', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""))` or `pd_series.apply(lambda row: re.sub(r'\([^()]*\)', lambda x: x.group().replace(",", ""), row))`

Comment: The accepted answer is the most fitting solution there with all things being explained.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

data = "John Doe, model (dell, 24-inch)"

def replace(g):
    return g.group(0).replace(',', '')

print(re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', replace, data))
```

Prints:

```
John Doe, model (dell 24-inch)
```